# android - Анимация "лесенка"в GridView

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, у меня есть `GridView` размером 6*6. Мне нужно сделать анимацию "лесенка" при старте активности. Застрял на самой анимации. Вот по такому порядку айтемов должна происходить анимация. Начинается с верхнего левого угла, заканчивается в нижнем правом.

```
1
2,7
3,8,13
4,9,14,19
5,10,15,20,25
6,11,16,21,26,31
12,17,22,27,32
18,23,28,33
24,29,34
30,35
36
```

Очень глупо по отдельности анимировать все по порядку. Хочу создать цикл, но написав `for` уставился в мигающий курсор и туплю. Как это можно сделать?

Насчёт адаптера, вообще, тупик. Он же перебирает все по порядку, слева-направо, а мне-то нужна лесенка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        for (int i = 1; i < 37; i++) {
        if (i == 1) {
            Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i);
        }
        else if (i == 2) {
            Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5));
        }
        else if (i == 3) {
            Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5) + " , " + (i + 10));
        }
        else if (i == 4) {
            Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5) + " , " + (i + 10) + " , " + (i + 15));
        }
        else if (i == 5) {
            Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5) + " , " + (i + 10) + " , " + (i + 15) + " , " + (i + 20));
        }
        else if (i == 6) {
            Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5) + " , " + (i + 10) + " , " + (i + 15) + " , " + (i + 20) + " , " + (i + 25));
        }
        else if (i == 12) {
            Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5) + " , " + (i + 10) + " , " + (i + 15) + " , " + (i + 20));
        }
        else if (i == 18) {
            Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5) + " , " + (i + 10) + " , " + (i + 15));
        }
        else if (i == 24) {
            Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5) + " , " + (i + 10));
        }
        else if (i == 30) {
            Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5));
        }
        else if (i == 36) {
            Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i);
        }
    }
```

С помощью `switch`

```
   for (int i = 1; i < 37; i++) {
        switch (i) {
            case 1:
                Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i);
                break;
            case 2:
                Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5));
                break;
            case 3:
                Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5) + " , " + (i + 10));
                break;
            case 4:
                Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5) + " , " + (i + 10) + " , " + (i + 15));
                break;
            case 5:
                Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5) + " , " + (i + 10) + " , " + (i + 15) + " , " + (i + 20));
                break;
            case 6:
                Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5) + " , " + (i + 10) + " , " + (i + 15) + " , " + (i + 20) + " , " + (i + 25));
                break;
            case 12:
                Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5) + " , " + (i + 10) + " , " + (i + 15) + " , " + (i + 20));
                break;
            case 18:
                Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5) + " , " + (i + 10) + " , " + (i + 15));
                break;
            case 24:
                Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5) + " , " + (i + 10));
                break;
            case 30:
                Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5));
                break;
            case 36:
                Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i);
                break;
        }
    }
```

С помощью `switch` немного короче

```
      for (int i = 1; i < 37; i++) {
        switch (i) {
            case 1:
            case 36:
                Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i);
                break;
            case 2:
            case 30:
                Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5));
                break;
            case 3:
            case 24:
                Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5) + " , " + (i + 10));
                break;
            case 4:
            case 18:
                Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5) + " , " + (i + 10) + " , " + (i + 15));
                break;
            case 5:
            case 12:
                Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5) + " , " + (i + 10) + " , " + (i + 15) + " , " + (i + 20));
                break;
            case 6:
                Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5) + " , " + (i + 10) + " , " + (i + 15) + " , " + (i + 20) + " , " + (i + 25));
                break;
        }
    }
```

Результат

```
I/TAG: i :   - 1
I/TAG: i :   - 2 , 7
I/TAG: i :   - 3 , 8 , 13
I/TAG: i :   - 4 , 9 , 14 , 19
I/TAG: i :   - 5 , 10 , 15 , 20 , 25
I/TAG: i :   - 6 , 11 , 16 , 21 , 26 , 31
I/TAG: i :   - 12 , 17 , 22 , 27 , 32
I/TAG: i :   - 18 , 23 , 28 , 33
I/TAG: i :   - 24 , 29 , 34
I/TAG: i :   - 30 , 35
I/TAG: i :   - 36
```

Comment: Цикл большой какой-то

Comment: Решение с вашим совпадает, подставляете вместо логов свою анимацию, возможно с задержкой и вуаля. Буду признателен вам если увижу решение более изящное. Мне было интересно, вот мой вариант.